# Node child process, channel closed on process.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

Inside my worker file I listen for a data callback. `someLib` is node-serialport.

```
process.on('message', function(msg) {
    someLib.on('data', function(data){
        console.log('some data');
        process.send(data);
    });
});
```

This prints

```
some data
Error: channel closed
```

But

```
process.on('message', function(msg) {
    process.send('foobar');
});
```

works fine. It is strange but sometimes the first code example works, so the channel closed error appears randomly.

From http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error I get the info that the error is triggered when

```
Sending a message to the child process failed for whatever reason.
```

What is "whatever reason"? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that forked child processes were not closed correctly when parent was killed. This resulted in multiple ghost processes that caused the channel closed error.

I hooked into the SIGHUP and killed them gracefully. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the event type, since with `process.send(data)` you're just sending an object.

Comment: What type? According to http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle there does not need to be a type

Comment: Yes, but in your code you're registering an event listener every time a message is received. I think you want to call a function there. So instead of `someLib...` just call the function directly like `process.send(data)`. Or you can do something what is [just below](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_server_object) where you've pointed me.

Comment: Sry you misunderstood me, someLib.on is called once, my code was just a short version. I edited my question.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. I guess the problem is in the `someLib` somewhere.

Comment: Must be, would like to find out.